# How can I remove the duplicated code in this code?

Tags: c++

this is some function:

```
RequestResult MenuRequestHandler::joinRoom(RequestInfo requestInfo)
{
    RequestResult requestResult;
    JoinRoomRequest joinRoomReq;
    joinRoomReq = JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::deserializeJoinRoomRequest(requestInfo.buffer);
    JoinRoomResponse joinRoomRes;

    if (this->m_roomManager.isRoomExists(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
        !this->m_roomManager.getRoomState(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
        !this->m_roomManager.isRoomFull(joinRoomReq.roomId)) 
    {
        joinRoomRes.status = 1;

        this->m_roomManager.addUserToRoom(this->m_user, joinRoomReq.roomId);
        try {
            requestResult.newHandler = m_handlerFactory->createRoomMemberRequestHandler(m_user, this->m_roomManager.getRoomDataById(joinRoomReq.roomId));
        }
        catch (MyException& e) {
            Log(e.what());
            // *this*
            joinRoomRes.status = 0;
            // *and this*
            requestResult.newHandler = nullptr;
        }
    }
    else {
        // *appear here*
        joinRoomRes.status = 0;
        // *and here*
        requestResult.newHandler = nullptr;
    }
    
    requestResult.buffer = JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(joinRoomRes);
    return requestResult;
}
```

i want to remove the duplicated code but i can't figure out a way to do it.
it tried another way but that's another duplicated code, like this:

````
RequestResult MenuRequestHandler::joinRoom(RequestInfo requestInfo)
{
    RequestResult requestResult;
    JoinRoomRequest joinRoomReq;
    joinRoomReq = JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::deserializeJoinRoomRequest(requestInfo.buffer);
    JoinRoomResponse joinRoomRes;

    if (this->m_roomManager.isRoomExists(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
        !this->m_roomManager.getRoomState(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
        !this->m_roomManager.isRoomFull(joinRoomReq.roomId)) 
    {
        joinRoomRes.status = 1;

        this->m_roomManager.addUserToRoom(this->m_user, joinRoomReq.roomId);
        try {
            requestResult.newHandler = m_handlerFactory->createRoomMemberRequestHandler(m_user, this->m_roomManager.getRoomDataById(joinRoomReq.roomId));
            // *this below*
            requestResult.buffer = JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(joinRoomRes);
            return requestResult;
        }
        catch (MyException& e) {
            Log(e.what());
        }
    }

    joinRoomRes.status = 0;
    requestResult.newHandler = nullptr;
    // *appear here below*
    requestResult.buffer = JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(joinRoomRes);
    return requestResult;
}
```
````

Comment: Please pick one version you'd like to be reviewed. It would also help if you posted the rest of your program, even if that means you need to post a couple files.

Comment: We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight can you give me an example of title you shouldn't do as you mentioned and what to do ?

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile please see the help center page [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It includes some examples of generic titles to avoid, as well as examples of **Some typical titles**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RequestResult MenuRequestHandler::joinRoom(RequestInfo requestInfo)
> ```

Is it necessary to copy the `RequestInfo`? or could we pass it by `const &`?

---

> ```
> JoinRoomRequest joinRoomReq;
> joinRoomReq = JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::deserializeJoinRoomRequest(requestInfo.buffer);
> ```

There's no need to split this into two lines. We should initialize variables to useful values immediately where possible.

---

> ```
> if (this->m_roomManager.isRoomExists(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
>     !this->m_roomManager.getRoomState(joinRoomReq.roomId) &&
>     !this->m_roomManager.isRoomFull(joinRoomReq.roomId)) 
> {
> ```

Rather than checking for success (which means indenting code, and adding an `else` statement further down), it's better to check for failure and return early.

We should avoid using `this->` unless it's actually necessary (which it isn't here).

Whatever `getRoomState()` returns, it seems unintuitive to treat it as a boolean (where `true` means something went wrong???). We should either give the function a better name (e.g. `isRoomActive`), or use an `enum class` for the result.

---

> ```
>     joinRoomRes.status = 1;
>
>     this->m_roomManager.addUserToRoom(this->m_user, joinRoomReq.roomId);
>     try {
>         requestResult.newHandler = m_handlerFactory->createRoomMemberRequestHandler(m_user, this->m_roomManager.getRoomDataById(joinRoomReq.roomId));
>         // *this below*
>         requestResult.buffer = JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(joinRoomRes);
>         return requestResult;
>     }
>     catch (MyException& e) {
>         Log(e.what());
>     }
> ```

Is this really correct if the handler creation fails? We've already added the user to the room, and set the status to `1`. I suspect this might result in problems later. Perhaps we need to remove the user from the room again and return failure (or restructure our code so that the user isn't added until we get the handle - perhaps `addUserToRoom` could return the handle)?

Also, we shouldn't use "magic numbers" (the `status` of `1` doesn't mean anything to someone reading the code for the first time) We should use an `enum class` for the status instead, which would give each value a meaningful name.

I wonder if exception handling is really the right thing to use in case of failure here... but it's impossible to tell without seeing more code. Perhaps the logging could be moved into the handle creation function, which could return a `nullptr`.

---

Putting the above points together (and taking some liberties by removing the exception handling), I'd suggest something like:

```
RequestResult MenuRequestHandler::joinRoom(RequestInfo requestInfo)
{
    auto const req = JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::deserializeJoinRoomRequest(requestInfo.buffer);
    auto const roomId = req.roomId;
    
    if (!m_roomManager.isRoomExists(roomId) || m_roomManager.getRoomState(roomId) || m_roomManager.isRoomFull(roomId))
        return { nullptr, JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(JoinResponseStatus::Failed) };

    auto handler = addUserToRoom(m_user, roomId);

    if (!handler)
        return { nullptr, JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(JoinResponseStatus::Failed) };

    return { handler, JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(JoinResponseStatus::Success) };
}
```

There's some duplication but it's easy to factor it out into a helper function (or the `RequestResult` constructor).

This still isn't very clean though. Note that we're doing two separate things: messing around with JSON, and performing the actual logic of adding the user to the room.

We should probably put all the logic for adding the user (and getting the handle) in the `addUserToRoom` function, and do the JSON stuff in the `joinRoom` function, e.g.:

```
RequestResult MenuRequestHandler::joinRoom(RequestInfo requestInfo)
{
    auto const req = JsonRequestPacketDeserializer::deserializeJoinRoomRequest(requestInfo.buffer);
    auto const roomId = req.roomId;

    auto const handler = addUserToRoom(m_userId, req.roomId);
    auto const status = (handler ? JoinResponseStatus::Success : JoinResponseStatus::Failed);
    
    return { handler, JsonResponsePacketSerializer::serializeResponse(status) };
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions that are likely to get closed.  Once you've answered, that [limits what can be done to improve the question](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body), making it more likely that your efforts are wasted.  It's better to wait until the question is properly ready before you answer!

Comment: @TobySpeight Considering the age of the question, I can understand the confusion.

Comment: thank you very much, although it is very old and aren't relevant anymore, but it sure helped me understand some good practices and good structures of the good, thanks.